# How to stop IFS function always giving the same result for x even if greater than x or less than x

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

`C9` being the group size, these are the formulas I used:

1. `=IFS(C9<5, "0%",C9>=5,"15%", C9>=15, "25%", C9>=40, "40%")`
2. `=IF(C9<5,"0%",IF(C9>=5,"15%",IF(C9>=15,"25%",IF(C9>=40, "40%"))))`

`C9 = 43` but the result of both calculations is still showing 15% instead of 40.

Answer (score 0):

The order of your `IFS` needs to be changed.

**How the [`IFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145) function work:**

> **Evaluates multiple** conditions and **returns** a value that corresponds to **the first true condition**.

In your formula, since your second condition is `C9>=5,"15%"` everything greater than 5 will give a `15%` result. **After that, the formula stops checking the following conditions**.

Try the following:

```
=IFS( C9>=40, "40%",C9>=15, "25%",C9>=5,"15%",C9<5, "0%")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works and makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.